# how to strip namespaces with e4x?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, e4x

I have an arbitrary XML document provided by a URL.  I also have an xpath-like expressions.

```
var xml = <doc><node1><node2><node3>some value</node3></node2></node1></doc>;
var path = "node1.node2.node3";
```

I need to verify if the above path into the XML is valid.  I tried to do this using eval and E4X.

```
var value = eval("xml."+path);
```

However, my actual xml document has namespaces which are getting in the way.  I do not know the namespaces ahead of time or care what they are.

Is there a way to strip all the namespaces out ahead of time?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In E4X you can use a wildcard for namespace prefixes. So if you transform `node1.node2.node3` into `*::node1.*::node2.*::node3` your `eval` will match, ignoring namespaces.